# Is it useful to install DNSCrypt-proxy with Tor?

Tags: anonymity, security, dns

Is it useful to install DNSCrypt-proxy when we already have Tor?
Does the ISP knows my internet queries when I use Tor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DNSCrypt](https://dnscrypt.org/) encrypt the communication between the client, and the resolver. If you are worried about DNS leaks, DNSCrypt can add an extra layer of security.

To answer your last question, your ISP doesn't know which websites you are visiting when you're using Tor.